# Increase receive buffer size for QTcpSocket

Tags: qt, sockets, qtcpsocket

Is it possible to increase [`QTcpSocket`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html#details) receive buffer size?

There are two methods to control Qt's socket receive buffer size:

[`void QAbstractSocket::setReadBufferSize()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#setReadBufferSize)

> Sets the size of **QAbstractSocket's internal read buffer** to be size
>   bytes...

and

[`void QAbstractSocket::setSocketOption()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#setSocketOption)
with the [`QAbstractSocket::ReceiveBufferSizeSocketOption`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#SocketOption-enum) parameter:

> Sets the socket receive buffer size in bytes **at the OS level**. This
>   maps to the **SO_RCVBUF** socket option. This option does not affect the
>   QIODevice or QAbstractSocket buffers (see setReadBufferSize()). This
>   enum value has been introduced in Qt 5.3.

The default value of void `readBuffer` is 0, that matches the unlimited Qt's own internal buffer:

> buffer size of 0 means that the read buffer is unlimited and all
>   incoming data is buffered. This is the default.

Therefore I try to change the OS-level receive buffer size via `setSocketOption`:

```
my_Soc->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::ReceiveBufferSizeSocketOption, 64 * 1024 * 1024);
```

after that I check the value:

```
int increasedSize = my_Soc->socketOption(
        QAbstractSocket::ReceiveBufferSizeSocketOption).toInt();
```

The `increasedSize` matches the value `64 * 1024 * 1024` what I've set. But really the size of the receive buffer stays equal to the **default value == 8 kilobytes.**

Is it possible to increase the buffer size, and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *"But really the size of the receive buffer stays equal to the default value == 8 kilobytes."*. How did you measure this 8 kilobytes? and why are you trying to increase the buffer size?

Comment: @Mike , I suppose it by losing packets, which happens only after some synchronous operation, and also I see that RAM memory using doesn't increase in diagnostic tools in my IDE

Comment: Try QAbstractSocket::waitForReadyRead: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForReadyRead. Not saying that is directly answering your question yet.

Comment: Is the sender application checking that data has been sent successfully? If it is using Qt, you can check the return value of `write()` and connect to the `bytesWritten()` signal...

Comment: Are you able to receive the complete stream when using another receiving application (e.g. `nc` if you are on unix)? The problem might be in the sending side; if it is not checking the result of a failing call to send (due to full send buffers for instance)...

Comment: **The answer is simple**: the default size is **unlimited**, you **cannot** increase it. Perhaps you have a code design issue (i. e thread blocking code) which causes data loss.

Comment: For Windows, setting this value to anything did not help, while the default only worked best.